# Cern ROOT - How to read contents from a TTree root file into array

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am trying to read data in from a Cern ROOT TTree file. I have not used root before and I am struggling a bit with this. I am familiar with C++, so can sort the array side of things, but I have been through several tutorial pages online and haven't got anywhere.

How do I read data from a TTree file? I assume it would be done by iterating over the tree's nodes (again, I'm not exactly sure how the file is organized?) inside a for loop?

Here is an example of the sort of reference I have been trying to follow.

https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/using-macro-read-ttree

As I understand it this is a generic question, but TTree's are not generic? (Since they could contain different variable names, I think?)

So, further information, which I think is important is:

By opening the root object browser `TBrowser b` - and browsing to the '.root' file, (and double clicking it) I can see that there are 12 variables in the file. For example, one is called 'mass', 'charge', etc...

Hope that's enough info? If not I can provide more.

Comment: If the answer below solves your problem, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: It does not solve the problem therefore I will not be marking it as accepted. Thank you for your concern

Comment: In what was does it not solve your problem?

Comment: It does not solve the problem. That is the way in which it does not solve the problem

Comment: I only meant that if you could be more specific about your problem, I might be able to help :). I use both of these methods regularly and they generally work fine.

Comment: Right... Well I'll have to put my solution on here at some point

Answer (score 5):

This page seems to show nicely how this can be done: https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/TTreeReader.html

The shortest usage example for your case would be:

```
TFile file("filename.root");
TTreeReader reader("treename", &file);
TTreeReaderValue<float> mass(reader, "mass"); // template type must match datatype
TTreeReaderValue<float> charge(reader, "charge"); // name must match branchname
...
while (reader.Next()) {
    // use *mass, *charge, ...
}
```

In the *olden* days, there used to be a more manual way of doing the same thing. You had to redirect the branches of the tree to your local variables. This method looks like this:

```
TTree* tree = (TTree*) file.Get("treename");
float mass, charge, ...;
tree->SetBranchAddress("mass", &mass);
tree->SetBranchAddress("charge", &charge);
...
for (int i = 0, N = tree->GetEntries(); i < N; ++i) {
    tree->GetEntry(i);
    // use mass, charge
}
```

From the TBrowser you can read off the names of the branches that you need to supply as the second paramter to `TTreeReaderValue` or `SetBranchAddress`.

Basically you should think of `TTree` as a collection of entries (classical *trees*). Each of the entries is made up of branches (*nodes*). This is how you read it.

Comment: How do I use mass and charge etc? EG, how would i cout the values in that while loop?

Comment: Everything is written in the answer: when you create a `TTreeReaderVaue` wrapper around the variable, you can use it as though it were a pointer: `cout << *mass << " " << *charge << ...`.
That's for the first case, in the second one you would just use the variables.

Comment: Ah I see so .Next() moves to get the next variable. I assume it returns true when there is valid next data? Is there any way to go back, say .Previous()?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I attempted to use your first method, cout'ing all the variables in the while loop... but no output is produced, suggesting the file is empty. (It is not.)

Comment: It seems `TTreeReader` is a root6 interface I don't have experience with yet. You should mention what root version you are using, and try the second method I showed. With that you should be able to go back and forth by simply selecting the appropriate entry. Also do the following so that I can help you further:
1. open the file in the interpreter as a `TFile` and do a `file.ls()`.
2. for everything mentioned there do `file.Get("name_of_thing")` and call `Print()` on the pointer that is returned.
Append both things to the question, because otherwise its impossible to debug file problems.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the slow reply - I am using a version of Root 6, the latest "pro" version. Here is the output from the opening as TFile:

TFile**  PhaseSpaceSimulation.root 
 TFile*  PhaseSpaceSimulation.root 
  KEY: TTree PhaseSpaceTree;1 Tree containing data for decays

Comment: Your second section of code, which I have just tried to use, does not run: should `tree->GetEntries`, in the for loop initialization be `tree->GetEntries()`. I tried both - the first gives a compiler error, the second gives a SEGFAULT.

Comment: Yes it should be `tree->GetEntries()`. Can you run the script under a debugger and figure out why the segfault?  Also do `TTree* tree = (TTree*) file.Get("PhaseSpaceTree"); tree->Print()` to figure out the structure of the tree.

Comment: Could be that the variables (mass/charge) need to be `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: Oh yeah, seems to be working now, used the second method. Thank you for your help - I will have to wait until next weekend to work on this again as I have gotten behind with other work, so I'll update and hopefully upvote and accept in the near future. Thanks again

Comment: what is the advantage of using TTreeReader?

Comment: Type safety. Using `SetBranchAddress` ROOT cannot verify that there is enough space at the address that is passed to it, this can easily segfault when mistakes are made.